# How do you prove family tie when asked US Visa?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas, applications

Please I will like to know how to prove that I am the one who is supporting a family member at home. I am the one who is sponsoring our last born at the University.  I have a US tourist visa interview scheduled for October this year so I just want to be prepared. a

While I was doing some research online and I came across this "We will focus on whether you have anything that ties you to your home country, for example, work, property, a spouse or family members whom you are supporting".

Thank you in advance for any answer you can give. I think my questions are different from the other ones that have already been asked on this platform.

Comment: Proof of financial support would include your bank statements showing funds transferred to your family member’s bank account. Proof of ties could be evidence that the family member *lives with you* and/or that they *rely on you* for help with daily living tasks, such as shopping, cleaning their home (if they don’t live with you) - basically, anything that requires your *physical presence* in your country of residence and is therefore a compelling reason for you to return home at the end of a trip.

Comment: Thnk u . None of my family members lives wit me & also I am a resident of another country, I chose to apply 4 d visa in my home country cos I feel dat I ve a strong tie to my home country than the country of residence eg. d country where I reside, I have business, credit and my bank is not that strong because the business that I do, does bring out money every time. While back home I have a business which has been registered over a year plus ago but I don't have a business account but I have been using my personal account to run the business, I don't know if that will be a problem for me.

Comment: But I have been doing this business for some years before I got it registered a while back, I also have properties and a good bank statement. I don't know if it's going to be a problem I am applying 4rm my home country too

Comment: So, you’ve applied from your home country where you have a year-old business and no family ties. You reside in another country where you also have a business, properties, but no family ties. The US operates a presumption of immigrant intent when making decisions on non-immigrant visa applications, IMHO the scenario you’ve set out is not going to convince them to approve your application

Comment: I have a business, properties and almost all my family member lives in my home country where I am applying for the visa, I pay my tax there too. In my country of residence, I only have a business of 5 years old and pay my tax too... As I explained to you before, I am the one taking care of our lastborn through the university. My problem is that I don't really understand the meaning of family ties. I am not married and I don't have any kids yet but I have a girlfriend and we live together in my country of residence.